# console is not defined

Tags: jquery

Why does this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log("test");
});
```

produce this error message:
console is not defined

In Firefox 3.5.6 on Windows XP?

Comment: I've had multiple instances of this error being fixed by a FF restart.

Comment: You have to have the firebug console up when the page refreshes.  You can't open the page, open the firebug console and then see the console output.  Firebug must be open when the page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Firebug version are you using? I had the same problem with version 1.4.5 in Firefox 3.5.6 on MacOS. What I did is, I installed the latest beta version from http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/1.5X/

After that it worked perfectly again.

Answer (score 7):

The [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) defines the console object in Firefox. It needs to be installed or there will be a JS error.

Comment: Annie, thanks for the answer.
But I'm looking at the error in firebug.  :(

Comment: Definitely try upgrading Firebug. If that doesn't work, try again on a new profile: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing+profiles#Creating_a_profile